# android get data from activity and display in html

Tags: android, html, webview, parameter-passing

I wanted to put variable from my activity and display it in html. Below is how I insert the variable into webview but I'm not sure how am I suppose to get the data from html and display it in "textview" form?

**EDIT**

**Java**

```
    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/com.example.hybrid/hybrid_user");
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:callFromActivity(\""+userid+"\")");
```

**html**

```
<body>
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Hybrid Application</legend>
        <p>
            <label>UserName: </label> 
        </p>
        <p id="mytext">Hello!</p>
        <p>
            <label>Mobile Number :</label>
            <input type = "text"
                        id = "mobileNum" />
        </p>
            <button type="button" 
            onclick="updateRecord()">Submit</button>    
                <div id="output"></div> 
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

```
 <script>
    function errorHandler(transaction, error){
        alert('Error:'+error.message+' (Code '+error.code+')');
        return true;
    }
    window.onerror = errorHandler;
    var shortName = 'hybrid_user';
    var version = '1.0';
    var displayName = 'Hybrid Database';
    var maxSize = 65536;
    var db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);

    function updateRecord(id, textE1){
        database.transaction(function(tx){
            tx.executeSql("UPDATE hybrid_user SET mobile = ? WHERE userid = ?", [textE1.innerHTML, id], null, onError);
        })
    }

    function callFromActivity(msg){
        document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = msg;          
    }
</script>
```

I'm new to html and I don't know what's wrong with my code, it did not display out the `userid` in the html page. Any comments and answers will be appreciated!

**Edit update**

```
 webView.loadUrl("javascript:callFromActivity(\""+userid+"\")");
```

Apparently is the system didn't go through this line of code. Is there anyway go through this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:callFromActivity(\""+userid+"\")");
        }
    });
```

I solved my problem with this. When the page loads finished it will execute the above code and get the `userid` from the activity.

Answer (score 0):

try change innerHTML for value like this:

```
function callFromActivity(msg) {
   document.getElementById("mytext").value = msg;          
}
```

Comment: I tested that out and still return as Hello! but not my userid